# Запрос единичной строки из базы данных в Room

Tags: android, android-room

как запросить например на отображение в `TextView`  имя работника по id из базы данных, чтобы можно было через логи посмотреть или через `TextView`?
Да я знаю что в начале надо сделать запрос в `@Query`  типо такого

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id IN (:idList)")
List<Employee> getByIdList(List<Long> idList);
```

а как дальше реализовать? чую что через LiveData. или лучше всего через DataBinding? В интернете в основном представлены варианты с адаптером recyclerview
(пример кода из адаптера):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RoomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
    Employee employee = EmployeeList.get(position);
    // SETTEXT IN RECYCLERVIEW
    holder.contacts.setText(employee.getContacts());

}
```

Вообщем - как вывести одну определенную строку, по id в активити?

Comment: LiveData и DataBinding -- каждый сам по себе. Или быть не может. Разделите вашу проблему на две части: научитесь данные получать (LiveData или без), а уже потом отображать (DataBinding или без).

Comment: Пока я так понял - можно комбинировать Room с SharedPreferences, как найду решение - как получить единичную строку из БД  - напишу здесь ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось извлечь данные из базы данных с помощью `ViewModel`.

```
private EmployeeViewModel employeeViewModel;
String name;
int position = 1;
```

Далее например в методе OnCreate работаем с ViewModel, извлекаем данные

```
 employeeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EmployeeViewModel.class);
    employeeViewModel.getAllEmployees().observe(this, new Observer<List<Employee>>() {
             @Override
           public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Employee> employees) {
              
              Employee currentEmployee = employees.get(position); // Employee - класс Entity
              name = currentStation.getName() // исходя из позиции указанной раннее извлекаем имя
                        
        
          }
    });
```

Код из @DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM employee_table ORDER BY id ")// DESC is used to sort the data returned in descending order
    LiveData<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees();
```

Answer (score 2):

Что же его так долго искать, это решение :)

Можно, конечно, и в списке `List<Employee>` поискать нужного человека, но правильно будет добавить в DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = :id")
Employee getEmployeeById(Long id);
```

Comment: хорошо, как запрос делать понятно,  а как отобразить данные в активити?                                                  
Через адаптер я понимаю как сделать, с `recyclerview` там через номер позиции,                                           а вот как  тупо в `TextView`  вывести данные запроса (вывод данных одного сотрудника по id) - я не понял пока))